# Blender 2.9 Crashing upon Render using Animation Nodes. Image and Animation

Tags: rendering, animation-nodes

Blender 2.9 Crashing upon Render using Animation Nodes. Image and Animation
I am using an RTX 2070 so I don't think it's my GPU and I should have plenty of memory. It is the first time trying to render a scene Utilizing the Animations Nodes ADDON but nothing else is different from past renders. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You might gain some insight by running Blender from the command-line (so you can see the error after it crashes) and find the .crash.txt file for more clues. Please post back with more info: What version of animation nodes are you using? What is the reported cause of the crash? Also, post a screenshot of your node graph. And post your .blend file.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the last AN version, at this time it is animation_nodes_v2_2_windows_py37.zip

I also have crashes in 2.91, sometimes after 5 frames rendering, sometimes after 25 frames, so weird, I will check an older Blender version.....okay checking 2.83LTS...rendering for 40 frames now without crashing.

Looking good so far! Please try!

Freddy